# CSS' calc() in styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

Trying this:

```
const styledDiv = styled.div`
  ${props => props.takeViewportHeight && `min-height: calc(100vh-16px);`}
`
```

It's not working. Am I missing something about calc in styled components?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

A funny tip about CSS `calc`:

> whitespaces are required between +/-

meaning:

```js
const styledDiv = styled.div`
  ${props => props.takeViewportHeight && `min-height: calc(100vh - 16px);`}
`
```

should work

Comment: [First note on MDN's page about calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#notes) talks about this