# Error when using calc() with react-native and styled-components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

I'm using styled-components in react-native with the `calc()` function

```
const MyElement = styled(MyText)`
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(20% - 10px);
`
```

**Error**

> JSON value 'calc(20% - 10px)' of type NSString cannot be converted to YGValue. Did you forget the % or pt suffix?

I already found this solution ([CSS' calc() in styled-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60602090/css-calc-in-styled-components)). But I am already using whitespaces.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

React-native uses [yoga layout](https://yogalayout.com/) which doesn't support `calc`. Ideally try to position your elements using flex. Otherwise, create additional wrapper for the element, go with `left: 20%` on on it and add `-10px` on the element itself. Another option is to calculate `left` yourself from container width using [View#onLayout](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout) of that container. It is also possible to calculate it from screen width (if your element can be positioned based on screen width rather than parent width) with [Dimensions](https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions)

Comment: Ok, but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65135806/using-styled-components-on-react-native-how-can-i-calc-the-height-of-a-componen) they state that it can be used with react-native. In any case, thanks for the suggestions on how to do it without calc()! Much appreciated

Comment: Pretty sure that answer might not be correct, you could try and see that, for example, `calc(100%)` doesn't work, as well as units like `vh` and `vw` @jayhaluska